# Please help decipher this artist signature in Hebrew

Tags: 20th-century, art, hebrew, painting, europe

[image]I acquired a couple years 2 paintings by the same artist. From my research, the signature is in Hebrew. 
The paintings were acquired in Austin, Texas but I don't think these are from United States but imported from Europe. The depicted scenes are European. First one is a cityscape of maybe Paris and the other one is 2 boats in a port with a European building in the back. Seems to be mid 20th century

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8HsE.jpg]

Comment: Is this a question about history?